# Import URL in QField on iPhone not working

Tags: import, url, ios, dropbox

I have the prepared project files stored in a folder in my Dropbox. It is the link to this folder I enter in the “Import URL”-field (I have also tried pasting a link to a zipped version of it). Not working.

I have specified in the iPhone QField settings to have Dropbox as storage location. When reading about how to import URLs to iOS on the QField page it seems so straightforward. The example image they use is also a Dropbox link. What do I do wrong?

/ Henrik

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Dropbox yet. But with Google Drive, you need to use the download link and not the file sharing link

Regards
Nelson

Answer (score 0):

[The thread on this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/4044) could solve your problem.
In short, as explained above, you need to make sure you have the  download link. For Dropbox, this is done by replacing the `dl=0`in the url by `dl=1`. For Onedrive, this is done by replacing `?d=...` by `?download=1`.

Also, make sure the folder with the project is zipped and "flat" (i.e. the project is not in a subfolder), I am not sure it will work otherwise.